# The import org.atmosphere.annotation.Broadcast cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, atmosphere

Though i have added the following dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
               <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
               <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

i am getting the error in the following code:

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.atmosphere.annotation.Broadcast;
import org.atmosphere.annotation.Suspend;

import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/websocket")
public class ChatController {

             @Suspend
             @RequestMapping(value = "/suspend", method = RequestMethod.GET)
             @ResponseBody
             public String suspend() {
                 return "";
             }   

             @Broadcast(writeEntity = false)
             @RequestMapping(value = "/broadcast", method = RequestMethod.POST)
             @ResponseBody
             public String broadcast(String message) {
                  return "";//new Response(message.author, message.message);
             }   


}
```

help me to fix this issue

Comment: Its solved after adding the following dependency in pom.xml ::<dependency>
  <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
  <artifactId>atmosphere-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: You can add this as an answer and accept it as there arent other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved after adding the following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId> 
  <artifactId>atmosphere-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```